# How to create Unit-test Project in Visual Studio 2012 RC

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

I have a Project, and now I want to create new unittest project for it. But I don't know the way to do this. I have been add new Test Project to solution, how to point this test project to my target. Please help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do this much the same way you would add references to any other project...

Add a new test project, then add a reference to the existing project by clicking on the References folder and choosing Add Reference